# Do WITH statements work inside a trigger definition?

Tags: sqlite, triggers, common-table-expression

I am trying to create a trigger that adds parts back into stock in the Lots table when a work order is deleted from the Workorders table. It should also delete all references to the work order in the WorkorderLots table. This is the trigger definition I came up with.

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_WO BEFORE DELETE ON Workorders BEGIN 
WITH info AS 
    (SELECT (Part.Qnty * WO.Qnty) AS Qnty, Lot.LotNumber AS lotnum 
    FROM WO_Qntys AS Part 
    JOIN Workorders AS WO ON Part.Name = WO.Build 
    NATURAL JOIN WorkorderLots AS Lot 
    WHERE WONumber = OLD.WONumber)
UPDATE Lots SET Stock = Stock + 
                    (SELECT Qnty FROM info
                         WHERE lotnum = LotNumber) 
                    WHERE LotNumber IN (SELECT lotnum FROM info); 
    DELETE FROM WorkorderLots WHERE WONumber = OLD.WONumber; 
END
```

When I attempt to run this query, I get `Error: near "UPDATE": syntax error`. I'm suspicious that the `WITH` statement is what's giving me problems, but I can't say why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) says:

> Common table expression are not supported for statements inside of triggers.